# JMeter WebDriver sampler Windows/Basic authentication

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, webdriver

I am trying to run a scenario using WebDriver sampler in JMeter 5.5 and my application has windows authentication. I have tried all possible ways and am not able to pass the authorization.
I am using JMeter 5.5 version, with Selenium WebDriver 4.13.0 and Firefox 122.0, with groovy language.

I have tried passing the credentials in the URL and got to know that it is depricated.
I tried using the Dev tools, but am getting an error message:

```
DevTools devTools = WDS.browser.getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();

devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.of(10000), Optional.of(10000), Optional.of(10000)));
def auth = "admin:admin!";

String encodeToString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes());

Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
headers.put("Authorization","Basic "+encodeToString);
devTools.send(Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders(new Header(headers)));
```

Am getting `ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: javax.script.ScriptException: org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevToolsException: You are using a no-op implementation of the CDP. The most likely reason for this is that Selenium was unable to find an implementation of the CDP protocol that matches your browser. Please be sure to include an implementation on the classpath, possibly by adding a new (maven) dependency of` org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-vNN:4.13.0`where`NN `matches the major version of the browser you're using.` error.

I also tried using the HasAuthentication method, but am getting the following error:

```
Predicate<URI> uriPredicate = uri -> uri.toString().contains(url);
Supplier<Credentials> authentication = UsernameAndPassword.of("admin", "admin!");

((HasAuthentication) WDS.browser).register(uriPredicate, authentication);


WDS.browser.get(url);
```

Error: `ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'FirefoxDriver: firefox on windows (bbbfeb27-327f-4ad3-a18b-2c70c23059c9)' with class 'org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver' to class 'org.openqa.selenium.HasAuthentication'`

Request some help with either of these two methods or any other possible solution to pass the Basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at [FirefoxDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html) JavaDoc I fail to see that it extends [HasAuthentication](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/HasAuthentication.html) interface so you won't be able to use UsernameAndPassword authentication object.

You will either need to switch to [ChromeDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html) or inject the credentials into URL.

For example this code:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('https://guest:guest@jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Basic/')
WDS.log.info(WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath('//p[3]')).getText())
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Works just fine:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Hey Ivan,
Thanks for the quick reply.
I tried the URL method again, somehow it is not working for my application. It did work for the jigsaw website from JMeter. Could you please help with any other methods for Firefox browser?

Comment: If it doesn't work - it means that your application is protected by other mechanisms like digest, NTLM or Kerberos. You need to figure out what protocol is used and then see whether FirefoxDriver supports it or not. In majority of cases you will need a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) for building a proper [Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization). See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-jmeter) article for more details.

Comment: I guess the application is protected by NTLM. For normal HTTP request if I use HTTP Authorization manager with BASIC mechanism, the HTTP request script works fine. Not sure how I can achieve the same using WebDriver sampler and Firefox browser.

Comment: I tried with Edge browser today, am getting the version mismatch error while using Hasauthentication:
`org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevToolsException: You are using a no-op implementation of the CDP. The most likely reason for this is that Selenium was unable to find an implementation of the CDP protocol that matches your browser. Please be sure to include an implementation on the classpath, possibly by adding a new (maven) dependency of org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-vNN:4.13.0whereNN matches the major version of the browser you're using`
How can I overcome this error?